# How to run callback functions independently guide matlab

Tags: multithreading, matlab, callback, matlab-guide

MATLAB GUI with two push buttons exist. Each push button begins an execution of an infinite loop of reading a serial data from Com-Port(different). When I press a push button the while loop reading Serial port, but when I press the next push button, the *port1* stops and then the *port2* starts reading, and when I stops the *port2*, the *port1* resuming.So here my question is, how  all callback functions with while loops can work independently and simultaneously..

```
function samplegui_OpeningFcn(hObject, ~, handles, varargin)



handles.output = hObject;
handles.vec_A=[];
handles.vec_B=[];
handles.vec_C=[];

handles.vec_A_1=[];
handles.vec_B_1=[];
handles.vec_C_1=[];
guidata(hObject, handles);

function open_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) % push button1 to receive serial data.

cnt=0;

while 1

       % Getting data  from Serial Port
        get_lines=fgets(handles.se) % getting data from serial port 
           if~isempty(get_lines)
            cnt=cnt+1;   
       if strfind(get_lines,'T')   %Parsing data
       handles.vec_A=[handles.vec_A;[timet newword]];
       plot(handles.vec_A(:,1),handles.vec_A(:,2:end),'r'); % plotting

       % Same follows for parsing and plot vec_B and Vec_C
       drawnow(); % to update the Plots
       end
     end
Pause(.05);


end
guidata(hObject, handles);

function open2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) % push button2 to receive serial data.

cnt=0;

while 1

       % Getting data  from Serial Port
        get_lines=fgets(handles.se2) % getting data from serial port2 
           if~isempty(get_lines)
            cnt=cnt+1;   
       if strfind(get_lines,'T')   % Parsing data
       handles.vec_A_1=[handles.vec_A;[timet newword]];
       plot(handles.vec_A_1(:,1),handles.vec_A_1(:,2:end),'r'); % plotting

       % Same follows for parsing and plot vec_B and Vec_C
       drawnow(); % to update the Plots
       end
     end
Pause(.05);


end
guidata(hObject, handles)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this in MATLAB because it is only possible to execute *one task at a time*. The way around this would be to have a [`timer`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html) that listens to each serial port at a given interval and the push buttons start/stop this timer. You would not need a `while` loop with a `pause` in this case, you would just need a funciton that gets the data from a serial port once and call this function each time the timer fires.

```
%// Function called each time a timer is fired, gets data from specified serial port
function getData(hObject, handles, serialport)
    get_lines = fgets(serialport);

    if isempty(get_lines)
        return
    end

    if strfind(get_lines,'T')
        handles.vec_A = [handles.vec_A; [timet newword]];
        plot(handles.vec_A(:,1),handles.vec_A(:,2:end),'r');
        drawnow();
    end

    guidata(hObject, handles);
end

%// And for your button callbacks that will toggle the timers on/off
function open2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    if ~isfield(handles, 't2') || ~isvalid(handles.t2) || ~handles.t2.Running
        %// Create a timer that checks the serial port twice a second
        handles.t2 = timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...
                           'Period', 0.5, ...
                           'TimerFcn', @(s,e)getData(hObject, handles, handles.se2));

        %// Start the timer
        start(handles.t2);
    else
        %// Stop and destroy the timer
        stop(handles.t2);
        delete(handles.t2);
    end

    guidata(hObject, handles);
end

function open_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    if ~isfield(handles, 't1') || ~isvalid(handles.t1) || ~handles.t1.Running
        handles.t1 = timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...
                           'Period', 0.5, ...
                           'TimerFcn', @(s,e)getData(hObject, handles, handles.se1));
        start(handles.t1);
    else
        stop(handles.t1);
        delete(handles.t1);
    end

    guidata(hObject, handles);
end
```

**Update**

As mentioned by [@Hoki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3460361/hoki) in the comments, you could also set the `byteAvailableFcn` property of the serial connection which would automatically fire (somewhat assynchronously) when new data arrives. This would prevent you from having to periodically poll the serial port for new data.

```
function getData(serialport, hObject, handles)
    get_lines = fgets(serialport);

    if strfind(get_lines,'T')
        handles.vec_A = [handles.vec_A; [timet newword]];
        plot(handles.vec_A(:,1),handles.vec_A(:,2:end),'r');
        drawnow();
    end

    guidata(hObject, handles);
end

set([handles.se2, handles.se1], 'BytesAvailableFcn', @(s,e)getData(s, hObject, handles);
```

Comment: I tend to use timers too if the expected volume of data is significant, but you could also mention the built-in callback for the serial ports `byteavailableFcn`, which would also listen silently and fire when data arrives at the serial port.

Comment: @Suever Is it possible to save and plot the data from ports respectively !!

Comment: @MaK You could setup a separate callback for each serial port and do custom plotting within the callback.

Comment: @Suever I wrote three separate functions for serial port, get _data1,get _data2, get data3. And calling the timer functions with respective push buttons. Still I could not read the ports parallely.

Comment: @MaK As I said in the beginning, it is never going to be *truly* parallel. If you post some code of what you have I can help you figure out what is going wrong

Comment: @MaK You are still using a while loop. If you look at my examples I do not. If you use a while loop you will not be able to do what you want. You need to adapt your code to something similar to what I have

Comment: @Suever Yes.. without while loop.. It could not read continuously at the port.. It is giving matrix index mismatch when I use if loop.

Comment: @MaK Post your code that *does not* use a `while` loop and I can let you know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Suever : Please look the below answer with the edited lines. This what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
function samplegui_OpeningFcn(hObject, ~, handles, varargin)

    handles.output = hObject;

    handles.vec_A=[];
    handles.vec_B=[];
    handles.vec_C=[];

    handles.vec_A_1=[];
    handles.vec_B_1=[];
    handles.vec_C_1=[];

    guidata(hObject, handles);
end

function getData_1(hObject, handles, serialport)
    get_lines = fgets(handles.se_1);

    if isempty(get_lines)
        return;
    end

    if strfind(get_lines,'T')
        handles.vec_A = [handles.vec_A; [timet newword]];
        plot(handles.axes1,handles.vec_A(:,1),handles.vec_A(:,2:end),'r');
        drawnow();
    end

    guidata(hObject, handles);
end

function getData_2(hObject, handles, serialport) 
    figure;
    hold on;
    ax(1)=subplot(3,1,1);
    ax(2)=subplot(3,1,2);
    ax(3)=subplot(3,1,3);

    get_lines = fgets(serialport);

    if isempty(get_lines)
        return
    end

    if strfind(get_lines,'T')
        handles.vec_A_1 = [handles.vec_A; [timet newword]];
        plot(handles.vec_A_1(:,1),handles.vec_A_1(:,2:end),'r');
        drawnow();
    end

    guidata(hObject, handles);
end

function open2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    if ~isfield(handles, 't2') || ~isvalid(handles.t2) || ~handles.t2.Running
        %// Create a timer that checks the serial port twice a second
        handles.t2 = timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...
                           'Period', 0.5, ...
                           'TimerFcn', @(s,e)getData_2(hObject, handles, handles.se2));

        %// Start the timer
        start(handles.t2);
    else
        %// Stop and destroy the timer
        stop(handles.t2);
        delete(handles.t2);
    end
end

function open1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    if ~isfield(handles, 't1') || ~isvalid(handles.t1) || ~handles.t1.Running

        %// Create a timer that checks the serial port twice a second
        handles.t2 = timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...
                           'Period', 0.5, ...
                           'TimerFcn', @(s,e)getData_2(hObject, handles, handles.se2));

        %// Start the timer
        start(handles.t2);
    else
        %// Stop and destroy the timer
        stop(handles.t2);
        delete(handles.t2);
    end
end
```

It is similar code while you given.. added while loop because It could not read data continously at the port.

Comment: I have updated your post to actually be readable. Also fixed a few errors. There shouldn't be any issues with it as posted. If there are, post the exact error message.